# Use a variable into a sql statement - c interface

Tags: sql, c, sqlite, printf

I am new to SQLite but I need it in my c program to analyse tables.
If I use as sql statement:

```
char *sql;
sql = "SELECT * FROM table;";
```

it perfectly works. But I would like to have

```
sql = "SELECT X FROM table;";
```

where X is a variable to which I assign a different column name each time.
I have tried with

```
sql = "SELECT 'X' FROM table;";
```

but it does not work. Looking on the web, it is not clear to me if it is possible to use a variable to select columns and if I should pay attention to it. Any advice on how to proceed is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf).

you can write something like [pseudo-code]

```
sprintf(str, "SELECT %c FROM table;", p);
```

Note: Assumed `str` is allocated, `p` is of type `char`.

Comment: But that only works if the column is one character in length.

Comment: Sorry @LinusKleen sir, din't get you.

Comment: Sorry. *Column name* is what I meant. Specifically the one in the pseudo code variable `X`. `X`needs to be an (unsigned) integer for your code to work since `%c` is the formatter for a *single* character. `%s` would allow for strings. The docs you quoted mention this.

Comment: @LinusKleen Yes, absolutely. I did assume for a single `char` only for example purpose. :-)